# Webpage Always Loading or Browser Crash

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if I could execute these php scripts, the browser cannot load a webpage. It always shows "loading" at the tab/title bar and sometimes it can cause browser crash or heats the CPU.

```
while($contents=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users"))
{
   // some contents here...
}
```

The thing that can solve that problem is to make the script like this...

```
$showUsersData=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users");
while($contents=mysqli_fetch_assoc($showUsersData)
{
   // some contents here...
}
```

Why is the browser doing that behaviour? Is the code (first) can generate infinite records? How is that possible?

Comment: This, because mysql_fetch_assoc return non empty array in each loop and it's alway true so loop is infinite, try '$contents=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users")' and then `foreach($contents as $key=>$value)`

Comment: In the first snippet PHP is evaluating the entire expression, including running the query, on every iteration of the `while` loop. Every time the query is re-run the result set is recreated and the loop condition always  sees the first row.

Comment: Please explain to me in the comments why did you down-voted my question so that I can improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in your first loop, you are always do the query. So after the first record, you `select *` again, what makes an infinite loop.

At the second, you will have your result in that variable, and loop through on that.